# linux shell test `-d` on empty argument

Tags: linux, shell

Here is the code,

```
x=
if [ -d $x ]; then 
    echo "it's a dir"
else
    echo "not a dir"
fi
```

The above code gives me `"it's a dir"`, why? `$x` is empty, isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps related to the fact that the `ls` and `stat` command with no arguments act on the current directory rather than an error stating that '' is not a directory?

Comment: When you say "Null", don't you really mean "the empty string"? Otherwise I think you're talking about `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Alcott: Consider properly quoting your code. `if [ -d "$x" ]` behaves as expected.

Comment: @Gabe, I mean "the empty string".

Comment: @jørgensen, well, should I always do that?

Comment: Your original question was about the `[` command.  Your "Follow Up" is about shell quoting behavior, and should be a separate question.

Comment: @KeithThompson, well, am I supposed to write a new post about the `Follow Up`?

Comment: @Alcott: Yes, if you like.  It's a separate question, not particularly related to the original one.

Comment: @KeithThompson, ok, do it right away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
x=
if [ -d $x ]; then
```

is equivalent to:

```
if [ -d ] ; then
```

A simpler way to demonstrate what's going on is:

```
test -d ; echo $?
```

which prints `0`, indicating that the test succeeded (`[` is actually a command, equivalent to `test` except that it takes a terminating `]` argument.)

But this:

```
test -f ; echo $?
```

does the same thing.  Does that mean that the missing argument is both a directory and a plain file?

No, it means that it's not doing those tests.

According to the POSIX specification for the `test` command, its behavior depends on the number of arguments it receives.

With 0 arguments, it exits with a status of 1, indicating failure.

With 1 argument, it exits with a status of 0 (success) if the argument is not empty, or 1 (success) if the argument is empty.

With 2 arguments, the result depends on the first argument, which can be either `!` (which reverses the behavior for 1 arguments), or a "unary primary" like `-f` or `-d`, or something else; if it's something else, the results are unspecified.

(POSIX also specifies the behavior for more than 2 arguments, but that's not relevant to this question.)

So this:

```
x=
if [ -d $x ]; then echo yes ; else echo no ; fi
```

prints "yes", not because the missing argument is a directory, but because the single argument `-d` is not the empty string.

Incidentally, the [GNU Coreutils manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#test-invocation) doesn't mention this.

So don't do that.  If you want to test whether `$x` is a directory, enclose it in double quotes:

```
if [ -d "$x" ] ; then ...
```

Comment: yes, you're right. But with quoting, I found something which confuses me further, see my **Follow Up**.

Answer (score 1):

The `stat` system call, which your shell presumably uses to determine if is a directory, treats null as the current directory.

Try compiling this program and running it with no arguments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct stat s ;

  stat(argv[1], &s) ;

  if(s.st_mode & S_IFDIR != 0) {
    printf("%s is a directory\n", argv[1]) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not quite; if that were the case, then `if [ -f ]` would be false.  See my answer.  Good guess, though.